# How can I union all the DataFrame in RDD[DataFrame] to a DataFrame without for loop using scala in spark?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, union, rdd, lsh

val result is a spark DataFram and its column is [uid: Int, vector: Vector].
But the type of recomRes is RDD[DataFrame], how can I map union all the result in recomRes to  a DataFrame?

```
val recomRes = result.rdd.map(row => {
    val uid = row.apply(0)
    val vec = row.getAs[Vector](1)
    brp
       .approxNearestNeighbors(vectors, vec, 5)
       .withColumn("uid", lit(uid))
       .select("uid", "aid", "distCol")
}
```

I have tried for loop to deal with, but very very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use toDF() method after map.

You need to import sqlContext.implicits._

Comment: I have fixed it by recomRes.reduce((x,y) => x.union(y))

Comment: But I tested the program which threw NullPointerException, and I don't know why